# I'm trying to access an image that is in an object inside of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I made this button that randomly selects a League champion and displays the name. Now I'm trying to display the image that goes with the champion. I've done some manipulation to the JSON to get some data with Object.values to get the name to display. If I use .map() then I'll get all the images until I click the button and then only the generated name and image appears. I would like it to be blank until I click the button. Thanks.

```
class App extends Component {
 state = {
 randomChampion: [],
 runes: [],
 spells: [],
 items: []
}

async componentDidMount() {
try {
  const res = await fetch('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.24.2/data/en_US/champion.json');
  const champions = await res.json();
  console.log(champions);
  this.setState({
    randomChampion: Object.values(champions.data),
  });
} catch(e) {
  console.log(e);
 }
}

getChampion = () => {
this.setState({
  randomChampion: this.state.champions[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.champions.length)],
 })
};


render() {

console.log(Object.values(this.state.randomChampion));
const CHAMPION_SQUARE = 'http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.24.2/img/champion/';
// const endImageURL = Object.values(this.state.randomChampion.image.full);
// console.log(this.state.champions);

return (
  <div>
    <HeadsUp>
      <h1>ULTIMATE BRAVERY</h1>

       <p>Are you brave enough?</p>
     </HeadsUp>

     <button onClick={this.getChampion}>
         Please Not Teemo
     </button> 

    <ChampGrid>  
     {this.state.randomChampion.name}
     {/* <img src={`${CHAMPION_SQUARE}${endImageURL}`}/> */}
    </ChampGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your approach, you would need 2 different states to store the champion data:

1. `champions` state: stores all champions data you obtain from json
2. `randomChampion` state: store a randomly selected champion object

So you will first need to initialize both of these states:

```
state = {
  champions: [],
  randomChampion: {}
}
```

In your `componentDidMount`, after making the API call, you setState to `champions` state, not `randomChampion`:

```
// ... fetch data ...
this.setState({
  champions: Object.values(champions.data),
})
```

and now your `getChampion()` function would make sense, it simply pick a random champion and set it as `randomChampion`.

and finally you just render them like so:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <HeadsUp>
        <h1>ULTIMATE BRAVERY</h1>
        <p>Are you brave enough?</p>
      </HeadsUp>

      <button onClick={this.getChampion}>Please Not Teemo</button> 

      <ChampGrid>  
        {this.state.randomChampion.image
          ? <img src={`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.24.2/img/champion/${this.state.randomChampion.image.full}`} />
          : null}
        {this.state.randomChampion.name}
      </ChampGrid>
    </div>
  )
}
```

The image url goes like this:
`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.24.2/img/champion/<champion-image-name>`

Comment: I do this and the error I get is TypeError: Cannot read property 'full' of undefined.

Comment: Oh, that's because initially `randomChampion` is just an empty object, calling `.image` will get undefined, and `.full` on undefined threw the error. I fixed my answer.

Comment: Got it, thanks very much!!! Just needed to remove the ' / ' after ...full}.

Comment: @mwlai ah sorry, my bad. Image url can't end with `/`. Glad you made it work :)